# How do I stop my bullet point appearing in bold?

Tags: microsoft-word-2016, bullets

In Word 2016, I have a Style for bullet points, and every time that style appears in a table it appears in Bold, even if the 'B' icon is not highlighted. Clicking it switched the Bold off instead of on.

I created a new style to use only in tables, but only the first bullet appears normal - all following bullets are back in bold.

Comment: Is your text (after the bullet point) bold?

Comment: Yes. ``````````

Comment: Note: when asked for clarification, update ([edit]) the question. You can still address another user in comments to get their attention, but the idea is all relevant information should be in the question body. This way anyone can step in and hopefully help without digesting all the comments.